# How to save image in Unity that I get from Firebase?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I connect to Firebase from Unity, and get simple image from it. But I want to know how can I save this image for example in Assets folder of unity project?

```
void Start()
{  
    FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.DefaultInstance;
    Firebase.Storage.StorageReference path_reference = storage.GetReference("background/1.jpg")

    "SavetoAssets = storage.GetReference("background/1.jpg")" // something like that.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[This post](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/159309/unity-download-image-from-firebase-database) is almost what you need. I just expanded it with the FileIO part using [`FileStream.WriteAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream.writeasync) and used [`UnityWebRequestTexture`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture.html) instead of `WWW`:

```c#
private void Start()
{
    FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.DefaultInstance;
    Firebase.Storage.StorageReference path_reference = storage.GetReference("background/1.jpg");


    path_reference.GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(
        task => 
        {
           Debug.Log("Default Instance entered");
           if (task.IsFaulted)
           {
               Debug.Log("Error retrieving data from server");
           }
           else if (task.IsCompleted)
           {
               DataSnapshot snapshot = task.Result;

               string data_URL = snapshot.GetValue(true).ToString();

               //Start coroutine to download image
               StartCoroutine(DownloadImage(data_URL));
           }
       }
    );
}

private IEnumerator DownloadImage(string url)
{
    using (UnityWebRequest uwr = UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture(url))
    {
        yield return uwr.SendWebRequest();

        if (uwr.isNetworkError || uwr.isHttpError)
        {
            Debug.Log(uwr.error);
        }
        else
        {
            // Instead of accessing the texture
            //var texture = DownloadHandlerTexture.GetContent(uwr);

            // you can directly get the bytes
            var bytes = DownloadHandlerTexture.GetData(uwr);

            // and write them to File e.g. using
            using (FileStream fileStream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
            {
                fileStream.WriteAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

*Note: I don't use Firebase, Android nor iOs so I couldn't test this*